# Does MongoDB ensure unique _id field values when using a compound shard key with _id

Tags: mongodb

I want to initiate the sharding. as you know shard key is very important. I found, [MongoDB doesn't ensure unique _id field values when using a shard key other than _id](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#how-does-mongodb-ensure-unique-id-field-values-when-using-a-shard-key-other-than-id).

In our collections, username shoud be shard key. If i create compound shard key and use _id as second part of shard key, does mongoDB guarantee uniqueness of _id ?

Comment: It will make sure that the username and _id combination is unique but not specifically the _id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not ensure unique `_id` fields across shards when used as a compound key.

[The documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#unique-indexes) states :

> MongoDB can enforce uniqueness for the shard key. For compound shard
> keys, MongoDB will enforce uniqueness on the entire key combination,
> and **not for a specific component** of the shard key.

So you if you want mongo to enforce uniqueness of the email, then simply use the email as the shard key.

An email address has some randomness, which is good ([`_id` has some predictability](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#write-scaling) built in), but I suggest you use the email field as a [hashed shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/shard-collection-with-a-hashed-shard-key/).

Comment: In your example, would the shard key using `email` need to be unique? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB ensure uniqueness for all fields of a compound key. But I'm not sure if this is you are looking for. What happen if you have these documents ? {_id:12345,email:"test@test.com"} and {_id:4567,email:"test@test.com"}. The sharded key is unique, but you have the same email twice.

If you are looking for a unique email on all shards, you can try to create a proxy collection with an unique index.

[You have more information here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/)

Comment: The link you provided contradict your answer : "MongoDB will enforce uniqueness on the entire key combination, and **not for a specific component** of the shard key". @Sammaye's comment is the right answer.

Comment: Maybe my english is not good enough but I can not see what are you saying. I understand that uniqueness in sharded keys is guaranteed by the combination of both fields, so in my example there are two unique sharded keys.

But what happen if you don't want a duplicate email?